# Why doesn't my HTML script for my applet work?

Tags: java, html, applet

Here's my HTML script:

```
<Applet Code="click.class" width=100% Height=100%>
</Applet>
```

And here's my class

```
public class click extends Applet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Button increase, decrease; // These are two buttons
    int value = 0;

    public void init() {
        increase = new Button("Increase f***s");
        add(increase);
        decrease = new Button("Decrease f***s");
        add(decrease);

    }

    public boolean action(Event e, Object args) {
        if (e.target == increase)
            value++;
        if (e.target == decrease)
            value--;
        if (value > 5) {

        }
        repaint();
        return true;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("How many f***s do you give? " + value, 50, 80);
    }
}
```

It gives me an error saying wrong name or something, googled it and found out I had to change the dir, but to what? I'm stuck on this any help would be grateful, thanks in advance.

Java Plug-in 10.45.2.18
Using JRE version 1.7.0_45-b18 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

### User home directory = C:\Users\Sharkgaming

c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache

### 0-5: set trace level to

CacheEntry[http://shuleii.dk/Click/click.class]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Sat Dec 21 18:25:00 CET 2013,length=1443

Comment: It'd be great if you gave us the error.

Comment: `"an error saying wrong name or something"`??? Please show the actual error text. Don't paraphrase it.

Comment: Would you run program written by someone you don't know just because he asks you? Under your link can be literally everything, not necessary applet with code you posted. I (and probably most of other SO users) am not going to run it using your site. However running it on my machine can produce different error then you are facing. That is why you should always provide what errors you get.

Comment: Okay Pshemo that was smart said, didn't think about that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direcory of your HTML should be the same as your java class files. ALternatively, you can place your HTML in the same directory with a folder containing class files, but then you'd need to change your HTML a bit: `<APPLET codebase="classesFolderName" code="click.class" width=100% height=100%></APPLET>`

Comment: Thanks, productive answer.

Comment: Okay, so I take my whole project folder in? The bin, or only the folders inside the bin? Confusing first time

Comment: Ohh, but the directory of HTML and class file is the same, always been.

Comment: Consider testing your applet in some IDE, because they often have isolated run-environments that make it unnecessary to fight all the security alerts and stuff. What's more, an IDE would generate your HTML for yourself, so that you can see how it should look like. Applets in general can cause many problems, as they are quite out-of-use technology now, due to security and other problems.